# Azure SQL Server full-text search doesn't work for .doc .docx types

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to setup full-text search for table

[image: DocumentBody].

I did everything to make it work:

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_catalog 'DocumentsCatalog', 'create';
EXEC sp_fulltext_catalog 'DocumentsCatalog', 'start_full'
EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'dbo.DocumentBody', 'create', 'DocumentsCatalog',  'PK_DocumentBody'
EXEC sp_fulltext_column 'dbo.DocumentBody', 'Value', 'add', 0, 'Type'
EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'dbo.DocumentBody', 'start_change_tracking'
EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'dbo.DocumentBody', 'update_index'
```

Also to prevent the questions about supporting these types of documents by my database I did:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.fulltext_document_types 
WHERE document_type IN ('.doc', '.docx', '.html')
```

Output:

```
document_type |class_id                            | path    |version       |manufacturer
--------------|------------------------------------|---------|--------------|-----------------------
.doc          |64F1276A-7A68-4190-882C-5F14B7852019|    NULL |              |
.docx         |5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3|    NULL |              |
.html         |E0CA5340-4534-11CF-B952-00AA0051FE20|    NULL |  12.0.6828.0 | Microsoft Corporation
```

After that I inserted 2 documents  with types '.html' and '.docx'.

When I searching

```
SELECT *
FROM DocumentBody 
WHERE CONTAINS([Value], 'some html content')
```

it working as expected, but when I doing the same for '.docx' content, it returns nothing.

Does anyone know why full-text search for '.docx' or '.doc' type doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL database full text search does not support "binary" file formats like Office and PDF, only text formats (which includes html).

You can extract the text from Office documents programmatically, and store the extracted text in a full text indexed column

Comment: If it so what the reason to set type of the document? Do you have any reference to MSDN which describes these approach?

Comment: Extracting text is just a workaround - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasonz/2009/08/31/sample-parsing-content-in-c-using-ifilter/

Comment: Thanks Erik. 
I finally figured out. so, for local SQL Server I can install IFilters for different types of documents and use it as I expected. For Azure SQL Database it doesn't works because it is not supporting .doc and .docx types of document and I have to use described approach